# Outlook 2013 & Outlook Add-In :: MAPIFolderEvents_12_Event.BeforeItemMove Not Firing?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to implement Adrian Brown's very nice [Outlook Add-In code](http://adriandev.blogspot.com/2008/01/listening-to-calendar-events-with.html) and it works 2 out of 3 times.  `ItemAdd` and `ItemChange` events are firing as expected, but the event handler for `MAPIFolderEvents_12_Event.BeforeItemMove` does not appear to be doing anything - I don't even *hit* a breakpoint on the first line of the event handler.

### More Code for Clarity

This is the CalendarMonitor class; it monitors ItemAdd, ItemChange events on the Items collection of the folder, as well as BeforeItemMove on the MAPIFolder:

```
public class CalendarMonitor
{
    private Explorer _explorer;
    private List<string> _folderPaths;
    private List<MAPIFolder> _calendarFolders;
    private List<Items> _calendarItems;
    private MAPIFolder _deletedItemsFolder;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<AppointmentItem>> AppointmentAdded;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<AppointmentItem>> AppointmentModified;
    public event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs<AppointmentItem>> AppointmentDeleting;

    public CalendarMonitor(Explorer explorer)
    {
        _folderPaths = new List<string>();
        _calendarFolders = new List<MAPIFolder>();
        _calendarItems = new List<Items>();

        _explorer = explorer;
        _explorer.BeforeFolderSwitch += Explorer_BeforeFolderSwitch;

        var session = _explorer.Session;
        try
        {
            _deletedItemsFolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
            HookupDefaultCalendarEvents(session);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session);
            session = null;
        }
    }

    private void HookupDefaultCalendarEvents(_NameSpace session)
    {
        var folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        if (folder == null) return;

        try
        {
            HookupCalendarEvents(folder);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
            folder = null;
        }
    }

    private void Explorer_BeforeFolderSwitch(object obj, ref bool cancel)
    {
        var folder = (obj as MAPIFolder);
        if (folder == null) return;

        try
        {
            // Hookup events to any other Calendar folder opened.
            if (folder.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
                HookupCalendarEvents(folder);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
            folder = null;
        }
    }

    private void HookupCalendarEvents(MAPIFolder calendarFolder)
    {
        if (calendarFolder.DefaultItemType != OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The MAPIFolder must use AppointmentItems as the default type.");
        }

        // Ignore other user's calendars.
        if (_folderPaths.Contains(calendarFolder.FolderPath) || (!IsUsersCalendar(calendarFolder))) return;

        var items = calendarFolder.Items;

        // Store folder path to prevent repeating listeners
        _folderPaths.Add(calendarFolder.FolderPath);

        // Store a reference to the folder & items to prevent garbage collection
        _calendarFolders.Add(calendarFolder);
        _calendarItems.Add(items);

        // Add listeners
        ((MAPIFolderEvents_12_Event)calendarFolder).BeforeItemMove += Calendar_BeforeItemMove;
        items.ItemChange += CalendarItems_ItemChange;
        items.ItemAdd += CalendarItems_ItemAdd;
    }

    private void CalendarItems_ItemAdd(object obj)
    {
        var appointment = (obj as AppointmentItem);
        if (appointment == null) return;

        try
        {
            if (AppointmentAdded != null)
                AppointmentAdded(this, new EventArgs<AppointmentItem>(appointment));
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment);
            appointment = null;
        }
    }

    private void CalendarItems_ItemChange(object obj)
    {
        var appointment = (obj as AppointmentItem);
        if (appointment == null) return;

        try
        {
            if (AppointmentModified != null)
                AppointmentModified(this, new EventArgs<AppointmentItem>(appointment));
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment);
            appointment = null;
        }
    }

    private void Calendar_BeforeItemMove(object obj, MAPIFolder moveToFolder, ref bool cancel)
    { 
        if ((moveToFolder != null) && (!IsDeletedItemsFolder(moveToFolder))) return;

        var appointment = (obj as AppointmentItem);
        if (appointment == null) return;

        try
        {
            if (AppointmentDeleting == null) return;

            // Listeners to the AppointmentDeleting event can cancel the move operation if moving
            // to the deleted items folder.
            var args = new CancelEventArgs<AppointmentItem>(appointment);
            AppointmentDeleting(this, args);
            cancel = args.Cancel;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment);
            appointment = null;
        }
    }

    private bool IsUsersCalendar(MAPIFolder folder)
    {
        // This is based purely on my observations so far - a better way?
        return (folder.Store != null);
    }

    private bool IsDeletedItemsFolder(MAPIFolder folder)
    {
        return (folder.EntryID == _deletedItemsFolder.EntryID);
    }

    public AppointmentItem Item { get; set; }
}
```

### New Information:

I have done some additional "troubleshooting" and come up with more information:  on a whim, I created a new calendar in Outlook (while debugging) and lo and behold the `BeforeItemMove` event fires just like I expect it to when deleting an appointment in the new calendar, but it still doesn't work in the original.

If I exit the debug session and restart, neither calendar's event functions as expected, despite working fine earlier.  Any new calendar's `BeforeItemMove` event will work fine, until I close Outlook - then it's back to not responding.

I am hoping that this additional information will provide insight to those wiser than I.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the break point isn't being hit and an event isn't firing, have you checked the Modules window to see which DLLs and there VERSION are being loaded?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I couldn't find a "Modules" window.

Comment: Under the Visual Studio's Debug Menu > Windows > Modules

Answer (score 1):

calFolder variable must be declared on the global/class level to avoid being released by the Garbage Collector.

Comment: The `aCalendarFolder` has a reference stored in a `private List<MAPIFolder> folders` - do I still need to store a reference to the `MAPIFolderEvents_12_Events` cast as well?

Comment: No, that should be fine, but BeforeItemMove is problematic. Do you have all the latest service packs installed? Do you see the event fire in OutlookSpy (click Folder button, go to the Events tab, look at the log at the bottom of the page)?

Comment: OutlookSpy (great tip - thanks) says the event *is* firing, but I'm still not seeing execution of the method.  Out of curiosity, since `BeforeItemMove` is problematic, how would *you* determine which `AppointmentItem` had been deleted?

Comment: You can use the Items.ItemRemove event, but it does not pass the item being deleted as an argument since the item is already gone (MAPI events are asynchronous). You can use Redemption and its RDOItems.ItemRemove event (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm) - it passes the value of the PR_SOURCE_KEY property, but that means you need yo cache the value of the PR_SOURCE_KEY property from the contents table before you start listening for the events.

Comment: I've edited the question - could you review the new info?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "until I close Outlook - then it's back to not responding"? Does your code that sets up the event handlers run when Outlook restarts?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you declare the source object? Is it alive when the event should be fired?

Anyway, you may consider developing an inspector wrapper. See [Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716(v=office.14).aspx) and [How to: Implement a Wrapper for Inspectors and Track Item-Level Events in Each Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184620.aspx) for more information.

The sample project in C# and VB.NET is also available - [Outlook 2010: Developing an Inspector Wrapper](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Outlook-2010-Developing-an-c4470591).